# Printing arrays to .txt file

Tags: arrays, perl, printing

I am trying to print the first 250 entries in an array to a .txt file, but I am having some trouble. When I run the script as is, I get nothing in my output.txt file.

```
    #! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line;
my @array;
my $file = "moloch_chunker_output.txt";

open (OUT , ">","moloch_chunker_output.txt")or die "cant open: $!";
while ($line  = <>){
        chomp($line);
        push(@array, $line);
        if(@array == 250){
                print OUT @array;
}
}
```

I know that I'm missing quite a bit here, but I have tried a couple of other methods after the if statement.

```
if(array == 250){
         print "[", join(",",@array),"]","\n";
```

works exactly how I want. I just want it to be written to a .txt file instead of simply being printed to the screen. How can I print the array to a .txt file?

Comment: Your script works, but everything's in one line. Probably you don't need the `chomp` call.

Comment: Your script can be replaced with `perl -pe 'exit if $. > 250' > moloch.txt`

Comment: yes, you're right. i have to sheepishly admit that i was checking moloch_chunker_out.txt instead of moloch_chunker_output.txt. That being said, using

    print OUT @array;

prints everything, except without the formatting that i need; array entities separated by comma and with a "[" "]" at the ends of the array.

Comment: @Tim Peoples

The use of head is a brilliant idea, and would work perfectly however the <STDIN> consists of several thousand lines of entities, all of which need to be chunked into a single line made up of the 250. My next move is to flush the array and continue building at the 251st entry from <STDIN>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of stuffing everything into an array and then printing the array contents when its size gets to 250, perhaps you could simply start a counter and print each line as you see it (and then quit once you reach 250).  Kinda like:

```
$cnt = 0;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    print;
    last if ++$cnt >= 250;
}
```

Or... you could just run `head -250 moloch_chunker_output.txt` from the command line (and skip Perl altogether).